# How can I get the PNG representation from the UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to get the image from the `UIImagePickerController` but the image is being received as the original image and it's taking a big size and slowing my app. How can I get the **PNG** representation in this case:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        treatmentProtocolPhoto.image = selectedImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I would appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: i think you can't do this because `UIImagePickerController` gives you a original image.

Comment: but you can do this after get the image and than you convert it from data using `itemData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(<youeImage>);` gives you NSData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
let imgData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage)!
treatmentProtocolPhoto.image = UIImage(data: imgData)! 
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @RamiAmmoun yiu should use guard or if let to safely unwrapp it instead of forcing unwrapping it

Answer (score 1):

You can get the PNG version with:

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage)
```